# HTTP load failed while getting data from the service

Tags: ios, json, swift

Below code I have tried to get details from service. but am getting error as HTTP load failed
    import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        parseData()
    }
    func parseData(){
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default // Session Configuration
        let session = URLSession(configuration: config) // Load configuration into Session
        let url = URL(string: "Here is my service link"!
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler:
        {
            (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error!.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                do {
                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any] {
                        print(json)
                    }
                } catch {
                    print("error in JSONSerialization")    
                }
            }
        })
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Above is the code I have tried - please give some suggestions.

Comment: Is the url https? It could be failing on the SSL certfticate.

Comment: no its just http...the exact error is ask <A9C2A4EE-7BB9-438F-8C91-07A0872C68A3>.<1> HTTP load failed (error code: -999 [1:89])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to info.plist

```
  <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: @Swift_prasad you had already added it in info.plist then why are you accepting this as answer